# Correct word order using “deshalb” and “oder”

Tags: word-order

In an exercise about correct word order, my grammar book gives the following question:

> **Fehlersätze: Korrigieren Sie die Fehler in den Wortpositionen**.
>
> Original Text: *…Viele Leute wollen nicht mehr ohne Musik sein. 
>   Deshalb sie hören in der S-Bahn über Kopfhörer Musik, schalten im Auto
>   das Radio ein, hören zu Hause Musik über eine Anlage oder gehen sie in
>   Konzerte. ...*
>
> Corrected Text (in bold):  *...Viele Leute wollen nicht mehr ohne
>   Musik sein.  Deshalb **hören** sie in der S-Bahn über Kopfhörer Musik,
>   schalten im Auto das Radio ein, hören zu Hause Musik über eine Anlage
>   oder sie **gehen** in Konzerte. ...*

I am having difficulty parsing and constructing the second sentence in the right way.

Firstly, since the overall sentence starts with *deshalb* with multiples clauses, I decomposed the sentence into the following parts:

*deshalb* – Adverbial connector to the previous sentence

a)  *Sie hören in der S-Bahn über Kopfhörer Musik* – first possible activity

b)  *Sie schalten im Auto das Radio ein* – second possible activity

c)  *Sie hören zu Hause Musik über eine Anlage* – third possible activity

d)  *Sie gehen in Konzerte* – Fourth possible activity

*oder* – Main clause connector for the four possible activities

With these components, my version of the entire sentence comes together as:

*Deshalb* – Remains in first position

*hören sie in der S-Bahn über Kopfhörer Musik,* - verb take position behind *deshalb*, the adverbial connector

*schalten im Auto das Radio ein,* - *sie* should be after *schalten* but can be omitted since it is a repetitive element

*hören zu Hause Musik über eine Anlage* - *sie* should be after *hören* but can be omitted since it is a repetitive element

*oder* - clause connector for the list of activities

*gehen sie in Konzerte.* – *sie* should be after *gehen* and retained as per the original sentence.

Since my answer with "*gehen sie in Konzerte*" is incorrect, could someone guide me on the understanding of this sentence?

Source: (B2-C1) Grammatik aktiv, Cornelsen 2019, page 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that your book is trying to teach you that ***oder* occupies position 0 and *deshalb* position 1**. As long as the conjuncts following the first conjunct have no *sie* (indicated by an underscore in the following example), they are interpreted as main clauses with the verb in second position.

> Deshalb [hören **sie** in der S-Bahn Musik], [schalten _ im Auto das Radio ein], [hören _ zu Hause Musik über eine Anlage].

Now if you were to continue with

> oder gehen **sie** in Konzerte?

the verb would be in first position and we would have a yes-no question. Which is possible – see the following example – but not intended here.

> Deshalb hören sie also Musik, oder haben sie noch andere Gründe?
>   *So that is why they are listening to music, or do they have any other reasons?*

There are two ways to circumvent interpretation as a yes-no question. One could leave out *sie*. This would signal that the conjunct in question, *gehen in Konzerte*, is to be interpreted with the verb in second position just as the preceding ones. But that is not what the authors have in mind; you are not allowed to remove words, only to reorder them.

> Deshalb [hören **sie** in der S-Bahn Musik] oder [gehen _ in Konzerte]. *(correct, but not intended)*

Therefore, the correct alternative is

> [Deshalb hören **sie** in der S-Bahn Musik] oder [**sie** gehen in Konzerte].
>    *(correct and intended)*

where the second conjunct is independent of the first, that is: *sie* is not missing, but occupies first position.

Answer (score 1):

Think of 'und', 'aber', 'oder', 'denn' and 'sondern' as independent of what comes before or after them. Like the couplings between railway carriages (as Drach puts it) they are not to be seen as part of the clauses they link together, and so do not affect the word order.